# Search for files in multiple directories and delete (unlink)

Tags: php

I need a safe way to scan about 1000 directories located under "users".

The main users directory has another directory (people's name). That people's name directory stores the few bad files I would like to delete. So, instead of me going through them manually and deleting them, is there a way to run a script to delete those files?

There are multiple files that I need to remove in those people's name directories!

**Example**

```
users/john/badfile.xml
users/tim/badfile.xml
users/bob/badfile.xml
users/scott/badfile.xml
users/jess/badfile.xml
....
users/tom/badfile.xml
```

**Here is the final working code!**

```
  $users = scandir('test'); // First we get the users

  unset($users[0]); // We unset the first two elements, which are       useless
  unset($users[1]);

  foreach ( $users as $i ) // We loop through the folders
  {
   $contents = scandir('test/'.$i); // We repeat the same process

   unset($contents[0]);
   unset($contents[1]);

    unlink('test/'.$i.'/'.'badfile.php'); // File deletion
    unlink('test/'.$i.'/'.'badfile.xml'); // File deletion
    unlink('test/'.$i.'/'.'badfile.html'); // File deletion
    unlink('test/'.$i.'/'.'badfile.txt'); // File deletion

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something ? Also please add a bit more detail to your question an explain, which files you want to remove?

Comment: This isn't a job board, what have you tried and/or where are you stuck?

Comment: i think he's just asking if there is a way to run a script.. the answer is yes there is

Comment: I understand!  I'm just trying to get a start into the right direction!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! Do you guys know where I can start to look into this? Any methods?

Comment: look up `glob()` that uses wildcards (should work) or DirectoryIterator and `unlink()`

Comment: you can start here http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#110570.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should be able to delete the files inside each directory, but will not delete the directories.

Keep in mind that my working path was **C:\server\root\michael\folder**

```
$users = scandir('users'); // First we get the users

unset($users[0]); // We unset the first two elements, which are useless
unset($users[1]);

foreach ( $users as $i ) // We loop through the folders
{
        $contents = scandir('users/'.$i); // We repeat the same process

        unset($contents[0]);
        unset($contents[1]);

        foreach ( $contents as $i2 ) // Loop through files of each folder
        {
            unlink('users/'.$i.'/'.$i2); // File deletion
        }
}
```

Comment: This works great! - It does delete the files, but I don't want to delete all the files in the directory! Only the ones I pick! I changed the code a little bit. Any idea? Here is a screenshot of the error.

http://goo.gl/79x49S

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work! I removed the 2nd for loop!

Comment: @TimothyLogue you could/should edit the answer in order to show everyone what the final solution was. Otherwise, people visiting the question/answer, may not know what to do, or has been done that provided the final solution ;-)